# How to deal with different types of images for image classification (Black & White & RGB) ImageNet

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, classification

I'm trying to perform classification on some images from Tiny ImageNet dataset. I'm creating a training dataset and test dataset where the features are the numpy representation of the image. However, it seems like there are RGB images which are of shape `(64x64x3)` and black & white images which are only one channel `(64x64)`; so I can't simply flatten the collection of images into a 1d array as they give different sizes. What's the standard way of dealing with this discrepancy? Do I pad with 0's?

Comment: One possibility is to repeat the greyscale, single channel three times to make a 3-channel RGB image that happens to be grey `threeChannelImage = np.dstack((grey,grey,grey))`

Answer (score 1):

Two simple approaches come to mind:

1. You can either convert all RGB images to grayscale
2. You can also convert all grayscale images to RGB

You then have a uniform shape for your input.

In any case, `OpenCV` can handle both operations using `cv2.cvtColor()` and either `cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY` or `cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB`.

I'm certain there are more complex ways to represent an image independent of its color space, but I'd start with either of the two above.

Edit: Bear in mind that if you convert a RGB image to grayscale and then back to RGB that they will differ. However, if you plan on using image augmentation there's a good chance it won't impact the model too much.